# Avoid draggable objects to become "droppable areas" once dropped

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am experimenting with dragging items from one "droppable" div to another. I start with 2 blue "draggable" rectangles. When I drag one of them over one of the "red droppable" rectangles, these red rectangles become green (while the item is being dragged over). I use the `ondragover` and `ondragleave` to make this work.

A problem arises when I dropped a blue draggable rectangle (let's call it A) over another draggable blue rectangle that has been previously dropped into one of the red rectangles (let's call it B). When A hovers over B, then B becomes green as well. In other words, it becomes also a droppable area. Which I want to avoid...

The thing I don't understand is that I set for these blue rectangles:

```
ondrop="return false;" ondragover="return false;
```

So I thought this would prevent them to become droppable. Though it seems like as soon as they are appended to a droppable `div` (the red ones), then they inherit from the properties of the red rectangle they have been 'dropped' in. How can I prevent this to happen?

```js
function drag(ev)
{
 //ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
 ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ev.target.id);
 //console.log(ev.target.id); // id
}

function dragover_handler(ev)
{
 ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
 ev.preventDefault();
 var item = document.getElementById(ev.target.id);
 item.style.border = '2px solid green';
 //console.log(ev.target.id + " is being dragged over"); // id
}

function dragover_handler1(ev)
{
 ev.preventDefault();
}

function dragleave_handler(ev)
{
 var item = document.getElementById(ev.target.id);
 item.style.border = '1px solid red';
}

function drop_handler(ev, el)
{
 ev.preventDefault();
 var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
 console.log("here >>" + data + "<<");
 el.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
 //var item = document.getElementById(ev.target.id);
 el.style.border = '1px solid red';
}
```

```css
html
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.to
{
 border: 1px solid red;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: block;
}

.from
{
 display: block;
 border: 5px solid blue;
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<body>

<p>Top List</p>

<div id="div1" class="to" ondrop="drop_handler(event, this)" ondragleave='dragleave_handler(event)' ondragover="dragover_handler(event)"> DROPPABLE AREA 1</div>

<div id="drag1" class="from" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="return false;" ondragover="return false;">draggable element 1</div>
<div id="drag2" class="from" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="return false;" ondragover="return false;">draggable element 2</div>

<p>Bottom List</p>

<div id="div2" class="to" ondrop="drop_handler(event, this)" ondragleave='dragleave_handler(event)' ondragover="dragover_handler(event)">DROPPABLE AREA 2</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key problem here is that `return false;` does not stop event bubbling or propagation for native events. (It does for jQuery events, which resulted in that concept being spread far and wide through the internet and which is probably why you're expecting it to behave that way).

What is happening then is when you drag over one of your draggable elements, it fires the event handler, which returns false on that event, and then bubbles up to its' container, which runs its own event handler. HOWEVER the `event.target` is still set to the original event!

You should be able to get your desired effect by adding `event.preventDefault();` in front of `return false;` in your draggable event handlers, like so:

```
<div id="drag1" class="from" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="event.stopPropagation(); return false;" ondragover="event.stopPropagation(); return false;">draggable element 1</div>
<div id="drag2" class="from" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="event.stopPropagation(); return false;" ondragover="event.stopPropagation(); return false;">draggable element 2</div>
```

You can see this functioning in a codepen here: https://codepen.io/kball/pen/PJPWmZ?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks for this complete and well documented answer. I appreciated you just didn't give the answer but provided the necessary background to learn something useful and the logic of the overall mechanism)) well done.